# Speech Emotion Recognition model predicting wrong classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, speech-recognition

I have created a model to predict emotion from a voice sample, the model is made from the code below:

there are total 8 emotions:
neutral, calm, happy, sad, angry, disgust, surprised

i first extracted the features of each and every voice sample and put them in a dataframe, then loaded
them one by one to both X and (labels to Y) then split the data as shown below:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, shuffle=True)

scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=2)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=2)

model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(units=8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()

rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.4, verbose=0, patience=2, min_lr=0.0000001)
history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=75, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[rlrp])
```

got total 89% accuracy

But when i try to predict any emotion, even with a voice sample from the training set, it always gives
"surprised" as the predicted emotion.

code below:

```
class livepredictions:
    
    def __init__(self, path, file):
        self.path = path
        self.file = file
        
    def loadmodel(self):
        self.loaded_model = keras.models.load_model(self.path)
        return self.loaded_model.summary()
    
    def makepredictions(self):
        x = []
        
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        
        x = extract_features(self.file)
        Features = pd.DataFrame(x)
        
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        scaler.fit(x)
        x = scaler.transform(x)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=2)
        
        predictions = self.loaded_model.predict_classes(x)
        print(predictions)
        print("Prediction is", " ", self.convertclasstoemotion(predictions))
    
    @staticmethod
    def convertclasstoemotion(pred):
        label_conversion = {'0': 'neutral',
                            '1': 'calm',
                            '2': 'happy',
                            '3': 'sad',
                            '4': 'angry',
                            '5': 'fear',
                            '6': 'disgust',
                            '7': 'surprised'}

        for key, value in label_conversion.items():
            if int(key) == pred:
                label = value
        return label
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: We never `fit_transform` the *new* data, as you do in your `makepredictions()` function; you need to have the initial scaler saved, and use `transform` instead.

Comment: changed it but no difference, still giving one label for all. Even for the test data set